JS Soap client for browser (JQuery.soap alternative)
Is there a modern soap client similar to jquery.soap or node-soap that can be used on a modern JS framework (vue, angular, react)?
I'm working with soap API and trying to avoid manually creating XML payloads.
I want to be able to use javascript objects instead and the plugin/utility would generate the required XML and also make the request (Optional).

I tried soap-everywhere which is a fork of browser-soap, which is a fork of tinysoap, which is a fork of node-soap and it just doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.
